# Send speech recognition args.Result as parameter in UWP desktop-bridge package

Tags: c#, events, uwp, parameter-passing, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to figure out, if it is possible send `using Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition;` `args.Result.Text` as parameter from **UWP** to **Console** application.

For example by following scenario I'm sending `TextToSpeech(args.Result.Text);` with `args.Result.Text;` value, where `using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis;` text-to-speech pronounces the recognition result each time when `args.Result.Text;` appears. `textBlock2.Text = args.Result.Text;` also displays result:

```
 private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(
            SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
        {
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {               
                textBlock1.Text = args.Result.Text;    

                TextToSpeech(args.Result.Text);               
            });
        }
```

but if I'm trying to send `args.Result.Text;` as parameter to console application, included with **UWP** in **Desktop-Bridge** package:

```
    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(
        SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {                            
          textBlock1.Text = args.Result.Text; 

          SendTTSResult(args.Result.Text);
        });
    }
```

to the requested function:

```
 private async void SendTTSResult(string res)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
            {
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] = res;
                await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters");
            }
        });
    }
```

Behavior of failure looks to me not really clear:

With first recognition result, it sends parameter to console application, which  successfully loads, gets and displays this parameter. But with second request the problem backs away from this processing level, even if parameters sending function is unambiguously the cause of a failure  `SendTTSResult(args.Result.Text);` function does not receives `args.Result.Text` but this happens already before function will comes in action, because preceding output display   `textBlock1.Text = args.Result.Text;` also does not receives event anymore.

With `async() =>` behavior is a bit different, it successfully receives event and sends value as parameter to console, in this case it happens 2-3 times from beginning of execution and voice requesting, then event disappears,  when it is not even passed through `SendTTSResult(string res)`, to imagine that the something in `SendTTSResult(string res)` does not allows pass string from recognition, but just stops, even if I put it in the end of `TextToSpeech(string text)` function, text to speech also stops receive event:

```
private async void SendTTSResult(string res)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async() =>
            {
                if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
                {
                    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] = res;
                    await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters");
                }
            });
        }
```

It looks like sending of `args.Result.Text` value as parameter with `SendTTSResult(string res)` function works fine, sends string successfully, but at the same time presence of this function in `ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated` somehow affects receiving of event inside of it. At the same time behavior of `ContSpeechRecognizer_HypothesisGenerated` looks completely different, `args.Hypothesis.Text` event appears each time and result  successfully passes as parameter with same `SendTTSResult(string res)`.

What can prevent an event from being executed when the function of sending a parameter is involved in its process, and how to fix it if possible?

*Full code of continuous speech recognition added to my question on Windows Dev Center [Send speech recognition args.Result as parameter in UWP desktop-bridge package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1af5f3d1-d5b2-4a0c-956c-53f550e8f1d1/send-speech-recognition-argsresult-as-parameter-in-uwp-desktopbridge-package?forum=wpdevelop)*

**EDIT 1:**  **************************************************************************************************

Behind parameter function, Console `Connector.exe` only shows parameter without running of any app or anything else:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            int index = result.LastIndexOf("\\");
            string rootPath = $"{result.Substring(0, index)}\\..\\";
            if (args.Length > 2)
            {
                switch (args[2])
                {
                    case "/parameters":
                        string parameters = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] as string;
                        Console.WriteLine("Parameter: " + parameters);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Packeage.appxmanifest:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
  <uap:AppService Name="SampleInteropService" />
</uap:Extension>

<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Connector\Connector.exe">
  <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
    <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="Parameters" Parameters="/parameters" />
  </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
</desktop:Extension>
```

**EDIT 2:**  **************************************************************************************************

I've tried `SendTTSResult(SpeechRecogVal);` with change of variable value:

```
 private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(
        SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {               
            SpeechRecogVal = args.Result.Text;
        });
    }
```

but it is same behavior `tbRec.Text = SpeechRecogVal;` shows output successfully until I add `SendTTSResult(SpeechRecogVal);`,

```
   private string _srVal;

    public string SpeechRecogVal
    {
        get
        {
            return _srVal;
        }

        set
        {
            _srVal = value;
            ValueChanged();
        }
    }

    void ValueChanged()
    {
        tbRec.Text = SpeechRecogVal;
        // SendTTSResult(SpeechRecogVal);
    }
```

So, seems like problem is something between `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>` and if `(ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))` and  `await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>` of `private async voidContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)`

Also, I've tried:

```
private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(
    SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
{
       await  SendTTSResult(args.Result.Text);        
}
```

as Task:

```
async Task SendTTSResult(string res)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
            {
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] = res;
                await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters");
            }
        });
    }
```

And it is also successful only with first request event instance response, then goes quite. So seems like `ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated` is someway different from other options in [Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechrecognition) and not compatible with something in   `async Task SendTTSResult(string res)` or rather with this code lines content:

```
 ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] = args.Result.Text;
 await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters");
```

Comment: For your requirement, I suggest you communicate with Console app with appservice. For more info please refer this [topic](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/).

Comment: @CoCaIceDew Hello, well, I've question on this here [System.NullReferenceException in AppServiceResponse and System.BadImageFormatException of UWP with WPF desktop bridge package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/55b79e1f-06f4-49c8-8e06-895c859fc4ce/systemnullreferenceexception-in-appserviceresponse-and-systembadimageformatexception-of-uwp-with?forum=wpdevelop), but particular task does not goes beyond package content, so, you're saying, that the `args.Result` cannot be passed as parameter to console?

Comment: I can't find where you pass the `args.Result.Text`  to console app. Could you point 
it out.

Comment: @Nico Zhu Hello, check my EDIT 1 please. Also you can check my question on Windows Dev Center: [Send speech recognition args.Result as parameter in UWP desktop-bridge package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1af5f3d1-d5b2-4a0c-956c-53f550e8f1d1/send-speech-recognition-argsresult-as-parameter-in-uwp-desktopbridge-package?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: So, you just store the text to to the local storage and fetch the data in the console app, right?

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT Yes, and it works fine with `ContSpeechRecognizer_HypothesisGenerated` `args.Hypothesis.Text` as well as not continuous Speech Recognition method `speechRecognitionResult.Text;`. So as fact, if event exist, function sends parameter  successfully, but by some reason including of `SendTTSResult(string res)` someway prevents event, for example for  previous `textBlock1.Text = args.Result.Text;`

Comment: We often use local setting to store some configuration information.It is not good practice, and I could not reproduce your problem,

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT So, you're saying that the `ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated` fires event with `SendTTSResult(string res)` included and sends string as parameter every time you make a voice request?

Comment: I mean that you could send the text with appservice when make a voice request every time.

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT Fact is that the `args.Hypothesis.Text` fires event, sends as parameter with included `SendTTSResult(string res)` and receives to console successfully, as well as with non Continuous method. Anyway, I've fully described my appservice problem with project repository included in last comment, but still can't fix it: [System.NullReferenceException in AppServiceResponse](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/55b79e1f-06f4-49c8-8e06-895c859fc4ce/systemnullreferenceexception-in-appserviceresponse-and-systembadimageformatexception-of-uwp-with?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Ok, I will check the `System.NullReferenceException in AppServiceResponse` issue

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT Thank you! And please, also check my EDIT 2, which is another attempt result in particular task

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException` occurs appservice disconnect scenario, Could you check the apservice's connection before send message?

Answer (score 1):

> System.NullReferenceException occurs appservice disconnect scenario, Could you check the apservice's connection before send message?

For explain this, I create sample project that refer **Stefanwick** [blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/). And I also reproduce your issue when I does not invoke `InitializeAppServiceConnection` method in WPF client. If you want to send text to wpf, you could invoke `Connection.SendMessageAsync` method just like below `SendMesssage` click envent .

**Capability**

```
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
          <uap:AppService Name="SampleInteropService" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="AlertWindow\AlertWindow.exe" />
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
```

**WPF**

```
private AppServiceConnection connection = null;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeAppServiceConnection();
}
private async void InitializeAppServiceConnection()
{
    connection = new AppServiceConnection();
    connection.AppServiceName = "SampleInteropService";
    connection.PackageFamilyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
    connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
    connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;

    AppServiceConnectionStatus status = await connection.OpenAsync();
    if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(status.ToString());
        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}

private void Connection_ServiceClosed(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceClosedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }));
}

private async void Connection_RequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // retrive the reg key name from the ValueSet in the request
    string key = args.Request.Message["KEY"] as string;

    if (key.Length > 0)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            InfoBlock.Text = key;

        }));
        ValueSet response = new ValueSet();
        response.Add("OK", "SEND SUCCESS");
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(response);
    }
    else
    {
        ValueSet response = new ValueSet();
        response.Add("ERROR", "INVALID REQUEST");
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(response);
    }
}
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ValueSet response = new ValueSet();
    response.Add("OK", "AlerWindow Message");
    await connection.SendMessageAsync(response);
}
```

**UWP**

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

     if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
     {
         App.AppServiceConnected += MainPage_AppServiceConnected;
         App.AppServiceDisconnected += MainPage_AppServiceDisconnected;
         await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
     }
 }

 private async void MainPage_AppServiceDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
     {
         Reconnect();
     });
 }



private void MainPage_AppServiceConnected(object sender, AppServiceTriggerDetails e)
 {
     App.Connection.RequestReceived += AppServiceConnection_RequestReceived;

 }
 private async void AppServiceConnection_RequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
 {
     string value = args.Request.Message["OK"] as string;
     await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
      {
          InfoBlock.Text = value;
      });


 }     
 private async void Reconnect()
 {
     if (App.IsForeground)
     {
         MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Connection to desktop process lost. Reconnect?");
         UICommand yesCommand = new UICommand("Yes", async (r) =>
         {
             await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
         });
         dlg.Commands.Add(yesCommand);
         UICommand noCommand = new UICommand("No", (r) => { });
         dlg.Commands.Add(noCommand);
         await dlg.ShowAsync();
     }
 }
 private int count = 0;
 private async void SendMesssage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     count++;
     ValueSet request = new ValueSet();
     request.Add("KEY", $"Test{count}");
     AppServiceResponse response = await App.Connection.SendMessageAsync(request);

     // display the response key/value pairs

     foreach (string value in response.Message.Values)
     {
         await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
         {
             StatusBlock.Text = value;
         });

     }
 }
```

This is complete code [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/AppSerViceTest).

Comment: Hello, would be correct post this answer on my another topic on this task: [System.BadImageFormatException in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926852/system-badimageformatexception-in-uwp-with-wpf-desktop-bridge-package) also supported on WDC: [System.BadImage](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/55b79e1f-06f4-49c8-8e06-895c859fc4ce/systemnullreferenceexception-in-appserviceresponse-and-systembadimageformatexception-of-uwp-with?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: This question not fully provoked by BadImage problem with creating of app connection in Package, but to Speech recognition event and parameters function interaction. I also imagine a different way, if I will receive parameter from CSR to console. So, I will put edit with results to your answer, please check **EDIT 5** here: [System.BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926852/system-badimageformatexception-in-uwp-with-wpf-desktop-bridge-package)

Comment: To look at problem, described in particular question, please, check my last comment on this topic [Send speech recognition args.Result](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1af5f3d1-d5b2-4a0c-956c-53f550e8f1d1/send-speech-recognition-argsresult-as-parameter-in-uwp-desktopbridge-package?forum=wpdevelop), which includes details and easy guide to build this [UWP_SR_desktop_bridge](https://github.com/ladooniani/UWP_SR_desktop_bridge) demo

Comment: So, I've have alternative idea of implementation, if I will get event result to console successfully, based on my main goal: [UWP Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis events](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/09fec565-ed4e-4b5d-be6d-bbc0c748dbe7/uwp-windowsmediaspeechsynthesis-viseme-speakprogress-speakcompleted-event-using?forum=wpdevelop) That's why would be correct and clear, keep this particular question on its own track

Comment: It is same `System.NullReferenceException` and `System.BadImageFormatException` please check [EDIT 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926852/system-badimageformatexception-in-uwp-with-wpf-desktop-bridge-package)